# Migrating Django Application to Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm developing a web application and considering Django, Google App Engine, and several other options. I wondered what kind of "penalty" I will incur if I develop a complete Django application assuming it runs on a dedicated server, and then later want to migrate it to Google App Engine.

I have a basic understanding of Google's data store, so please assume I will choose a column based database for my "stand-alone" Django application rather than a relational database, so that the schema could remain mostly the same and will not be a major factor.

Also, please assume my application does not maintain a huge amount of data, so that migration of tens of gigabytes is not required. I'm mainly interested in the effects on the code and software architecture.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most (all?) of Django is available in GAE, so your main task is to avoid basing your designs around a reliance on anything from Django or the Python standard libraries which is not available on GAE.

You've identified the glaring difference, which is the database, so I'll assume you're on top of that. Another difference is the tie-in to Google Accounts and hence that if you want, you can do a fair amount of access control through the app.yaml file rather than in code. You don't have to use any of that, though, so if you don't envisage switching to Google Accounts when you switch to GAE, no problem.

I think the differences in the standard libraries can mostly be deduced from the fact that GAE has no I/O and no C-accelerated libraries unless explicitly stated, and my experience so far is that things I've expected to be there, have been there. I don't know Django and haven't used it on GAE (apart from templates), so I can't comment on that.

Personally I probably wouldn't target LAMP (where P = Django) with the intention of migrating to GAE later. I'd develop for both together, and try to ensure if possible that the differences are kept to the very top (configuration) and the very bottom (data model). The GAE version doesn't necessarily have to be perfect, as long as you know how to make it perfect should you need it.

It's not guaranteed that this is faster than writing and then porting, but my guess is it normally will be. The easiest way to spot any differences is to run the code, rather than relying on not missing anything in the GAE docs, so you'll likely save some mistakes that need to be unpicked. The Python SDK is a fairly good approximation to the real App Engine, so all or most of your tests can be run locally most of the time.

Of course if you eventually decide not to port then you've done unnecessary work, so you have to think about the probability of that happening, and whether you'd consider the GAE development to be a waste of your time if it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you will change the data model base class and some APIs if you use them (PIL, urllib2, etc).

If your goal is app-engine, I would use the app engine helper http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/appengine_helper_for_django.html. It can run it on your server with a file based DB and then push it to app-engine with no changes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have awareness of the major limitation in building/migrating your app -- that AppEngine doesn't support Django's ORM.

Keep in mind that this doesn't just affect the code you write yourself -- it also limits your ability to use a lot of existing Django code. That includes other applications (such as the built-in admin and auth apps) and ORM-based features such as [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/).

Comment: AppEngines Datastores are modeled on Django's ORM http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html

Comment: Yes, indeed. That isn't really relevant to my point, however.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you can't do on the App Engine that you can do on your own server like uploading of files. On the App Engine you kinda have to upload it and store the datastore which can cause a few problems.

Other than that it should be fine from the Presentation part. There are a number of other little things that are better on your own dedicated server but I think eventually a lot of those things will be in the App Engine